# Tkinter :Plotting mulitple graphs ,the GUI get crashed and windows says python program not responding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

In my tkinter GUI i have two buttons which plot graph for different parameters but when i click on one of the button , the graph plots successfully and I am not embedding the matplotlib window in any other tkinter window , I am directly calling the matplotlib plot ,but when without closing one plotted graph if i click on another one then other graph windows opens and suddenly error comes that python program not responding. So do embedding the matplotlib plot in another toplevel window will help can't we call multiple plots without embedding them in tkinter window , Here is the sample code

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import mttkinter
import threading
def plottingthefirst():
    plt.figure()
    parameter1 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    plt.plot(parameter1, marks)
    plt.xlabel('parameter1')
    plt.ylabel('marks')
    plt.show()


def plottingthesecond():
    plt.figure()
    parameter2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    plt.plot(parameter2, marks)
    plt.xlabel('parameter2')
    plt.ylabel('marks')
    plt.show()

def func3():
    threading.Thread(target=plottingthefirst).start()
def func4():
    threading.Thread(target=plottingthesecond).start()
root = Tk(mt_debug=1)
root.geometry('445x788')


global marks
marks = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
B1 = Button(root, text="Plot1", command=func3).grid(row=1, column=1)
B2 = Button(root, text="Plot2", command=func4).grid(row=2, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

I need to call threading here because this is not the exact code what i am using basically I am doing a processing before plotting to extract the values of the x and y parameters so if i remove threading then my main  window will hang therefore i need threading here , so is there any solution that without removing threading we can display multiple graphs at the same time

Comment: This part of the code looks good to me.Could you post the full code?

Comment: @AfiJaabb sir actually this part of the code only giving me the error , please let me know where you are facing problem to understand ?

Comment: Can the two functions `plottingthefirst()` and `plottingthesecond()` be executed in main thread?

Comment: yes they can be but that will make hang the window because is also going on therefore seperate thread I have called

Comment: Since `matplotlib` is not thread-safe, you better use it in the main thread.  Also I don't see anything need to be executed in threads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216273/discussion-between-ankur-and-acw1668).

Answer (score 0):

Adding **plt.close()** at the start of both the functions should do the job.

Comment: What OP wants is ***"can display multiple graphs at the same time"***.